# How to make the value of a lengh macro change with another

Tags: macros, tex-core, conditionals, lengths

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgf,etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}
\newdimen\aaa
\newdimen\bbb

\ifnum 5>4 \def\ccc{\aaa}\else\def\ccc{\bbb}\fi

\aaa30pt\the\ccc|% typeset 0.0pt, not 30.0pt.  why does \the\ccc not typeset the length of \aaa?
\ccc40pt\the\aaa % typeset 30.0pt. how to make the length of \aaa change with \ccc?

% I also tried \let instead of \def, but give the same result.
\end{document}
```

Comment: it is better to use `\setlength\aaa{30pt}`.

Comment: What is the difference between `\setlength\aaa{30pt}` and `\aaa30pt`

Comment: the former is a wrapper of the latter. It adds a \relax at the end, hence it is more reliable.

Comment: @L.J.R. `\setlengts\aa{30pt}` is LaTeX specific construction but better is format independent `\aaa=30pt\relax`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're about, sorry. For one thing, `\aaa` and `\bbb` are ***not*** macros.

Let's examine

```
\newdimen\aaa
\newdimen\bbb

\ifnum 5>4 \def\ccc{\aaa}\else\def\ccc{\bbb}\fi

\aaa30pt\the\ccc|% typeset 0.0pt, not 30.0pt.  why does \the\ccc not typeset the length of \aaa?
\ccc40pt\the\aaa % typeset 30.0pt. how to make the length of \aaa change with \ccc?
```

You have defined `\ccc` as a macro that expands to `\aaa`. Now you do

```
\aaa30pt\the\ccc
```

Since `\aaa` is declared by `\newdimen`, if TeX finds `\aaa` when it's not looking for a dimension, it starts performing an assignment of a value to the register; it finds `30pt`, but the assignment is not yet performed, because, by rule, an optional space can follow the unit of measure, so TeX will expand `\the` ***before*** finishing the assignment. Since `\the` wants to see something it can apply to, TeX expands `\ccc` and finds `\aaa`. OK, we were in the middle of expanding `\the`, so TeX does it and the value of `\aaa` is still 0pt. So we're at a point where the input stream has

```
\aaa30pt0.0pt
```

Now the assignment can be performed and `0.0pt` is typeset.

The second case is identical, because

```
\ccc40pt\the\aaa
```

becomes

```
\aaa40pt\the\aaa
```

and at the end `\aaa` will be set to `40pt` and the *previous* value of `\aaa` is printed.

So you see that the cause of your problems is ***the missing space*** after `pt`. With

```
\aaa=30pt \the\aaa
```

TeX will happily print `30.0pt` and ***ignore*** the space.

Of course, if you're using LaTeX, you would do

```
\setlength{\aaa}{30pt}\the\aaa
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this detail information. And, `by rule, an optional space can follow the unit of measure,` What's the meaning of "optional space"? Would you say more about it?

Comment: @lyl “Optional space” is a precise syntactic object in the TeX language. In some situations (in this case, the lookup for a length), an `<optional space>` is part of the syntax; it means that such a space, if present, will be ignored, but it will be looked for with macro expansion. Just like constants, it's best to end an explicit length with a space or `\relax`. Caveat: the description above is a white lie, you can find more information in the TeXbook, in case you insist to use low level constructs without having read it in depth.